# JavaFX WebView/WebEngine won't load certain content

Tags: java, javafx, webview

The JavaFX WebView doesn't load the images on this specific web page: **https://500px.com/popular?categories=Landscapes**

and I don't know what's wrong. Cookies are definitely enabled and I've tried with cookies disabled too. I've tried setting the user-agent to a common browser.

I've tried with the simplest web view test:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setWidth(1280);
    primaryStage.setWidth(720);

    GridPane root = new GridPane();

    WebView webView = new WebView();
    webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().messageProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println(newValue));
    webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().exceptionProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println(newValue.toString()));
    webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println(newValue));
    webView.getEngine().setOnError(event -> System.out.println(event.getException().toString()));

    root.add(webView, 0, 0);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));

    primaryStage.show();

    webView.getEngine().load("https://500px.com/popular?categories=Landscapes");

}
```

The only error/status messages I get are:

```
Loading https://500px.com/popular?categories=Landscapes
SCHEDULED
RUNNING
Loading complete
SUCCEEDED
```

I'm stuck with the loading icon. The images load on chrome and if I disable cookies on the chrome browser, I get the same problem on the chrome. But I'm sure cookies are enabled; I even tested it on a cookie test website.

What's wrong and what can I do to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Caution: Linked site includes some tasteful nudity that is NSFW in some countries, including mine (USA).

Comment: You might be right about the cookies.  The page makes two GET requests to https://api.500px.com/v1/photos? *many query parameters…*  Those requests work when loaded from the page in a regular browser, but when I try to load them directly via `wget`, I get an HTTP 401 Unauthorized response.

Comment: I added `CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());` right before loading the page, and saw two logged errors: “Invalid cookie for javascripts://dialog.filepicker.io/dialog/comm_iframe/: testcookie” and “Invalid cookie for javascripts://www.filepicker.io/dialog/comm_iframe/: testcookie”

Comment: Just did the same and I get the same results. Must be that.

In Chrome dev tools, I can see that both the test cookies are there under the "dialog.filepicker.io" and "www.filepicker.io" domains. They have no name which is probably why it is invalid.